# How can I stop my belt from drifting off my sander?

Tags: safety, sanding

It is a simple question really that would be hard to embellish. While I'm using my belt sander the belt drifts. Sometimes almost half way off the assembly. This does not happen constantly but very often. Yes, there is a mechanism that prevent the belt from going to far the other direction (back towards the sander) but nothing that stops it from leaving (nor could it).

Is it pressure, technique, belt quality, belt sander quality. I've been trying variations of pressure and handling but it still slides off.

How can I keep my belt on properly?

Comment: The tracking adjustment should allow you to adjust it in both directions. If it isn't working that way I'd consult the troubleshooting section of the owner's manual or contact the manufacturer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tracking adjustment on the side to help keep the belt aligned.  I've noticed that different uses require adjustment.

The grit of the belt can make a difference and when I'm trying too 'hard' in one place. It will want to run off the sander.  If I can get it running straight without pressure (or just a little toward the inside) but it won't stay when sanding, likely it means I'm trying to use too much pressure, I need to back off and let the sander do it's job.